# What is the difference between Paillier additive homomorphic property and addition of two paillier ciphers

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

Paillier has additive homomorphic property that states:

1. if two ciphers c1 and c2, are multiplied, and the result is decrypted, it is equal to addition of the  two plaintexts.

D(c1*c2)= m1+m2

2. Paillier also allows two ciphers to be added. If the addition result is decrypted, we get the addition of the two plaintexts also.

D(c1+c2) = m1+m2

The two operations lead to the same result i.e., m1+m2.

However the second operation is only mentioned in [Paillier python  libraries](https://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/) and not in the formal definition of Paillier.

What is the difference between the two and if both are valid, is it true that Paillier has many-to-one homomorphic property.

The second property is mentioned in the python library pdf as follows:

Once this party has received some EncryptedNumber instances (e.g. see Serialisation), it can perform basic mathematical operations supported by the Paillier encryption:

1. Addition of an EncryptedNumber to a scalar
2. Addition of two EncryptedNumber instances
3. Multiplication of an EncryptedNumber by a scalar

Answer (score 4):

In standard [Paillier encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem)

- *Property 1* really is:
  $m_1=D(c_1)\text{ and }m_2=D(c_2)\implies D(c_1\cdot c_2\bmod n^2) = m_1+m_2\bmod n$.
- *Property 2* does not hold (but see final off-topic note).

As a consequence of *property 1*, for all $k$ in $\mathbb Z$, it holds $D({c_1}^k\bmod n^2)\ =\ m_1\cdot k\bmod n$. Proof for positive $k$ can be by induction, proof for negative $k$ follows from group properties of multiplication in $\mathbb Z_{n^2}^*$ and $\mathbb Z_n^*$.

Note: For integers $u$, $v$ and $w$, by definition of $u\bmod v=w$, that means $u-w$ is a multiple of $v$ and $0\le w<v$. The operator $\bmod$ has priority less than $+$ (thus less than $\cdot$) but more than $=$. Contrast with operator `%` in computer languages, which typically has priority more than `+`.

---

> Once this party has received some EncryptedNumber instances (e.g. see Serialisation), it can perform basic mathematical operations supported by the Paillier encryption:
>
> 1. Addition of an EncryptedNumber to a scalar
> 2. Addition of two EncryptedNumber instances
> 3. Multiplication of an EncryptedNumber by a scalar

That's correct if we take addition and multiplication modulo $n$. Given $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $m_1=D(c_1)$ and $m_2=D(c_2)$, and a scalar $k$ in $\mathbb Z$, any party knowing the public key $(n,g)$ can

1. Compute $c$ such that $D(c)=m_1+k\bmod n$, by encrypting $k$ and applying *property 1*. That is $c\gets c_1\cdot g^k\cdot r^n\bmod n^2$ for some $r$ coprime with $n$ (possibly $r=1$ if hiding $k$ and that $c$ derives from $c_1$ are pointless in the application).
2. Compute $c$ such that $D(c)=m_1+m_2\bmod n$, by application of property 1.
3. Compute $c$ such that $D(c)=m_1\cdot k\bmod n$, by application of the consequence of *property 1*.

---

The [doc](https://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/) linked in the question is for a [library](https://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) that adds a wrapper on Paillier encryption. [This](https://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/phe/paillier.html) is the part of the [source](https://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py-modindex.html) doing the crypto. The library handles negatives and floating point numbers, as explained [there](https://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/phe.html#module-phe.encoding), by

- Restricting it's plaintext integers to range $\left[\,-\left\lfloor n/3\right\rfloor,\left\lfloor n/3\right\rfloor\,\right]$, with negatives mapped to $\left[\,n-\left\lfloor n/3\right\rfloor,n-1\,\right]$ of standard Paillier encryption.
- Separating mantissa (encrypted with sign as above) and exponent (which remains in clear).

Off-topic: Python allows operator `+` to perform anything the programmer wants when applied to objects defined by the programmer. Both in the above library and the simpler [code](https://pypi.org/project/paillierlib/) linked in comment, `+` for two ciphertexts has been <strike>coerced</strike> overloaded to call an internal function that makes use of *property 1*, thus performs a multiplication modulo $n^2$. Similarly, `*` has been overloaded to call an internal function that makes use of the consequence of *property 1*, thus performs an exponentiation modulo $n^2$.

Comment: Can you check this library: https://pypi.org/project/paillierlib/    It says:                                 m1 = mpz(10)
m2 = mpz(1)
c1 = paillier.encrypt(m1, key_pair.public_key)
c2 = paillier.encrypt(m2, key_pair.public_key)

# Example homomorphic operations
# Addition
paillier.decrypt(c1 + c2, key_pair.private_key) # => 11
paillier.decrypt(c1 - c2, key_pair.private_key) # => 9
paillier.decrypt(c1 + c1 + c2, key_pair.private_key) # => 21

Comment: yes the source you mentioned is the correct one.

Comment: @Tasneem Ghunaim: your question turns out to be a programming one (thus off-topic), specifically about operator overloading, as explained in the answer's last paragraph. I expanded the butlast paragraph about what the pyphe library does.